# Convert column value to int in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I am working on this query and it is returning exception cannot convert `varchar` to `int`:

```
 SELECT BG_PRIORITY, count(*) as cnt 
 FROM Bug 
 WHERE BG_TARGET_REL= case when ISNUMERIC('XXXX 13.5') = 1 then 
 cast('XXXX 13.5' as int) else 'XXXX 13.5' end 
 GROUP BY BG_PRIORITY
```

This query is generated from my C# code. Where clause filter can be a numeric or string one as the user chooses the type of filter he/she wants and according gives its value.

Is there a approach so that I can add any type of filter in my query?

Comment: Is `BG_TARGET_REL` an int column?

Comment: you have to cast `BG_TARGET_REL` as according to your values too....

Comment: A `case` expression has to have a single result type that all possible values are/can be converted to. Since one of your results is `int`, it's trying to convert all possible results to `int`. Also, `ISNUMERIC()` is one of the flakiest functions you'll ever encounter, and should generally be avoided.

Comment: I am a little confused about what you are trying to do. You want to return all records that have a certain BG_TARGET_REL. Then the value you are comparing with has to be the same type as BG_TARGET_REL. Or am i understanding you wrong?

Comment: Yes `BG_TARGET_REL` is int one.. But this just for an example. User can select any field which can be an int or varchar one so I am testing it before comparing the value..

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for help can i get some refernce for this..

Comment: A column will only accept either INT or varchar. But in your query you  are trying to assign both int and varchar to the same column. It is not possible.

Comment: Why do you want to convert to int?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**IF** your only column types are `int` and `varchar`, then you can simply use this:

```
SELECT BG_PRIORITY, count(*) as cnt 
FROM Bug 
WHERE <ChosenColumn> = 'InputValue'
GROUP BY BG_PRIORITY;
```

This works by using SQL Server's implicit [data type precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) conversions.  If  is an int, the input value, something like `'123'` is converted to the number 123 (*exactly what we want!*).  If the column is varchar, the quoted value remains as a varchar.

---

Your original CAST error stems from the fact that a CASE statement results in one datatype and one only, using the same data type precedence rules linked above. Consider your branches:

```
case when ISNUMERIC('XXXX 13.5') = 1
     then cast('XXXX 13.5' as int)      --<< this branch returns int
     else 'XXXX 13.5'                   --<< this branch returns varchar
     end
       >> data type precedence ==>  resultant type of expression is "int"
```

When you give it a value 'XXXX 13.5', the case statement results in 'XXXX 13.5', which it then needs to cast to the `CASE expression resultant type`, i.e. int => fail.

Comment: Thanks.. The int value will be automatically be casted by sql server ?